# Where to put SSL

Tags: ssl, dns, certificate, free

I'm getting crazy with SSL certificates. After trying from lots of different providers I finally got one using [SSL for free](http://sslforfree.com).

But there's one thing that I haven't understood yet.

Do I have to upload my certificate on my Domain provider (such as [Register.it](http://Register.it)) or on my Host service (such as [000webhost](http://000webhost.com) or [InfinityFree](http://infinityfree.net))?

The problem is that [000webhost](http://000webhost.com) offers a better service but not the possibility to upload an SSL certificate on a free plan, while [InfinityFree](http://infinityfree.net) (which offers a worse service) does.

I have the possibility to upload my certificate on the Domain provider ([Register.it](http://Register.it)), but I can't understand if it works or it is overridden by [InfinityFree](http://infinityfree.net) one, and I have difficulties in trying switching from Host to Host because of the really slow DNS propagation.

Sorry if I made confusion, but it was to explain better my situation... My question remains one: *Do I have to upload my certificate on my Domain provider or on my Host service?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upload ssl certificate to your **hosting**. SSL for free is a  **Let's Encrypt** certificate.

You can check which provider ssl running on your domain.

**Step:**
Tab your browser **green lock icon** then **details**

Comment: I can't find it... Under [this](https://imgur.com/a/WAkr9A3) tab there's no provider field, is it the right tab?

Comment: I can see you have a comodo ssl

Comment: it is taken from internet... Just to know if I were into the right tab

Comment: I can't see my host service into this tab, only my domain name

Comment: Can you share me your live domain? or you can check is your doamin ssl enabled or not [ssl checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html)

Comment: Thanks, it works (if you want to check [this](https://www.typed.online) is my domain). The only problem is that the IP is slightly different (only the last byte) from my host service servername IP... Is it possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible because dns not find the host server.

Comment: So what does this mean? `typed.online resolves to 185.27.134.95` (from SSL Checker)

Comment: Doesn't it mean the nameserver which I use to park my host on?